# how to set apex scheduler every 5 minutes

Tags: apex, trigger, scheduled-apex

I have the scheduler class, when I was about to set the Apex scheduler, I noticed that I can only select the time which will be every hour but i need to run it every 5 minutes, can you give me some ideas to achieve this?

This is my scheduler class

```
global class CaseBreachTAT_Scheduler implements Schedulable{
   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
      CaseBreachTAT_Batch CaseBT_B = new CaseBreachTAT_Batch(); 
      database.executebatch(CaseBT_B);
   }
}
```

Comment: @AdrianLarson - this is not a duplicate as the answer you posted to clearly states it cannot be done and only speaks to the UI / cron. At a minimum it does not directly answer the question..I only bring it up because I reviewed that exact answer before posting..

Comment: Hmm, it asks how to schedule every 15, and says you should schedule multiple jobs. I feel like I've seen a 5 minute dupe even, just couldn't find it on my phone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to do this:

1. Schedule the batch like normal (This just starts it)
2. In the scheduler class do this to cancel the scheduled job when it runs the first time:

   ```
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
       batchJob batch = New batchJob();
       database.executeBatch(batch);

       //delete schedule            
       CronTrigger ct =
           [SELECT Id,
           CronExpression
           FROM CronTrigger
           WHERE Id = :SC.getTriggerId()];


               //Abort the job. A new one will be scheduled after the batchJob finishes
               System.abortJob(SC.getTriggerId());


     }
   ```
3. Then in your finish method of the batch do this:

   ```
   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

   system.scheduleBatch(New batchJob(),'New Batch Job - ' + DateTime.now().getTime(),15);      

   }
   ```

**Note** See adrian's comments below. This does not rune every five minutes but chains them 15 minutes after completion.

Comment: Do I still need to schedule the apex everyday or once the apex has been scheduled (say one day in a week)it will automatically trigger every 5 mins so I dont need to schedule it everyday?

Comment: It does not matter what you do as long as the schedule executes once. You really do not even need to schedule it. Just execute the batch job and it will schedule itself

Comment: @gelay - If it works for you please mark as the correct answer

Comment: So if the batch takes on average two minutes to execute, this will run roughly every seven minutes?

Comment: yup. Safest way to do it IMHO otherwise you have to account for all sorts of other issues, row locks, etc - but good to point out.

Comment: @Eric If we initially just schedule a batch or just run a batch for the first step, the abortJob in execute method  of Scheduler class will never execute ,right? Does it still make sense to have abort method in Scheduler class?